# hide img in span, css

Tags: css, kendo-ui

I am using kendoUI, I cannot change the html, they are generated by the framework.

I wish to remove/hide text in span and keep the image by clicking button. I cannot hide text only.

```
<span class="k-link">
    <img></img>
    menu text
</span>
```

Thank you

Comment: you can set `font-size: 0px` to hide the text on clicking the button for your class `.k-link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

**CSS**

```
.k-link{
    font-size: 0px;
}
```